# How can I add physics animations to a Flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

I’m trying to add an effect on a series of containers where they constantly move around a phone screen. This is similar to what is shown below, however they need to be able to bounce off each other too.

Has anyone tried something like this before and can point me on the right direction please? Worth noting that I need the containers to be widgets and so can’t just use a video.

Thanks a lot!

[image: Bouncing balls animation]

Comment: Are you looking for this, [particles_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/particles_flutter)?

Comment: Many thanks for the comment @JimChiu, it's not quite what I'm looking for but perhaps I can adapt it. Will take a look